# How to diagonalize a large sparse symmetric matrix, to get the eigen values and eigenvectors?

Tags: algorithms, matrix-decomposition

The matrix could be as large as $2500\times 2500$, what is the best algorithm to do that, is there some algorithm that is easy to write a program, is there any convenient packages for that?

Answer (score 10):

There is a survey of decomposition algorithms in the first table of [this NIPS paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1102.5597v1).

It lists *modern* algorithms (with links to known implementations), including the stochastic decomposition of [Halko et al.](http://users.cms.caltech.edu/~jtropp/papers/HMT11-Finding-Structure-SIREV.pdf), arguably the state-of-the-art method today.

You ask for convenient programming packages but don't state your platform or language of choice. Assuming it's:

- Python:

  - use [scipy](http://www.scipy.org/) for in-core decompositions (input must fit in RAM)
  - use [gensim](http://nlp.fi.muni.cz/projekty/gensim/) for both in-core and out-of-core sparse decompositions (also supports incremental decomposition updates)
- Java:

  - [Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org/) has several scalable decomposition algos
  - [LingPipe](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/svd/read-me.html) (in-core) supports missing input values
- C++

  - [redsvd](http://code.google.com/p/redsvd/) (in-core) very clean and elegant, efficient implementation
- MATLAB

  - [pca.m](http://cims.nyu.edu/~tygert/pca.m) by Mark Tygert, one of the co-authors of the stochastic method.

Your problem isn't particularly big though, so I guess any existing package (using the iterative Lanczos algorithm) will do fine, eigen decompositions have been around for a while.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I'm sure you will receive enough upvotes from this question to post as many links as you want in the future.

Comment: +1 Great answer: it offers many solutions, provides links to them all, and adds some advice about newer algorithms.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at Hernandez, V., et al. ["A survey of software for sparse eigenvalue problems."](https://slepc.upv.es/documentation/reports/str6.pdf) Universitat Politecnica De Valencia, SLEPs technical report STR-6 (2009).

Answer (score 4):

I don't know much about eigenvalues or what they are applicable to, but R seems to have a built in function for this purpose named `eigen()`. Calculating the eigenvalues & eigenvectors for a 2500 * 2500 matrix took ~ 1 minute on my machine.

```
> sampData <- runif(6250000, 0, 2)
> x <- matrix(sampData, ncol = 2500, byrow = TRUE)
> system.time(eigen(x))
   user  system elapsed 
  79.74    2.90   65.69
```

This question has also come up on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713878/how-expensive-is-it-to-compute-the-eigenvalues-of-a-matrix).

Answer (score 4):

2500x2500 is not such a large problem. Even without leveraging the sparsity the SVD implementation of scipy.linalg is able to decompose it in less than a minute. See [my answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4766/randomized-svd-and-singular-values/4981#4981) to a related questions for more details.

For larger problems you will need to use the sparsity explicitly. The [gensim](http://nlp.fi.muni.cz/projekty/gensim/) project my help you for middle size problems that fit on a single computer but not in RAM and the [mahout](http://mahout.apache.org) implementation is able to deal with sparse matrices that don't even fit on a single hard-drive.